# How to detect the ridgeline of a gully with small scale data (>1m) in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, elevation

I'm having trouble finding the outline of a gully in my DEM with a very large resolution. I've tried the [How to identify ridgelines from a DEM](https://support.esri.com/en-us/knowledge-base/how-to-identify-ridgelines-from-a-dem-000011289) method but it does not work with my data, I presume because the scale is too large that it detects microchanges in the terrain as individual rivers and channels. I haven't found any other method online that works with finding the ridgeline properly, does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: You might indicate was parameters you were using in the tool, and the DEM's key properties like cell size, units, coordinate system, etc.  You can also try using the watershed tools https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/how-watershed-works.htm

Comment: Try catchment delineation